# Recover deleted (by Windows) Android photos

Tags: data-recovery

I've accidentally deleted an Android folder containing some photos using my Windows laptop. I've already tried a bunch of recovery apps but none of them show the deleted photos (they do show photos deleted using the phone).

Is there any way to recover those photos?

My phone has Android 11 (Oneplus 7t), it's not rooted (bootloader is) and I was using MTP.

Comment: That device runs FBE+metadata encryption, impossible to recover deleted files. You can however scan for trash files and thumbnails with app com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free

Comment: @alecxs Is this the correct app you are recommending: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yes it can not restore deleted files, but it can find thumbnails of deleted pictures in hidden directories

Comment: Well, it didn't find those thumbnails, only older photos. So I guess it's not recoverable